# What is the use of boost::visit_each?

Tags: c++, boost

I read the [documentation on `visit_each`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/visit_each.html), but can't really see what exactly it does, as well as the general use for it, if every user has to overload it anyways. Someone care to enlighten me?

---

**Edit**: Maybe I'm just so confused because the following is the whole content of `<boost/visit_each.hpp>` and I just don't see any "magic" there to "visit each subobject":

```
namespace boost {
  template<typename Visitor, typename T>
  inline void visit_each(Visitor& visitor, const T& t, long)
  {
    visitor(t);
  }

  template<typename Visitor, typename T>
  inline void visit_each(Visitor& visitor, const T& t)
  {
    visit_each(visitor, t, 0);
  }
}
```

Maybe someone can give me a concrete example of how this is supposed to look like / work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the important part of that documentation is this line: "Library authors will be expected to add additional overloads that specialize the T argument for their classes, so that subobjects can be visited."  In other words, there is no general use for it, it is just a common name for any visitor-based introspection mechanism.  The way it is implemented, *something* will happen for all types, whether their writers were aware of its existance or not, so you don't get a compile-time failure.

It doesn't seem overly useful to me... practically speaking, it is just an internal function of the boost signals library, but I suppose if you're using that library anyhow specializing `visit_each` on your own types wouldn't hurt.

They mention finding `signals::trackable` objects. So presumably, they have provided a couple specializations for their own types within the signals library.  Then they have a `is_trackable` functor.  Or something similar.

```
struct trackable { };

struct Introspective {
    int a;
    double b;
    trackable c;
};

struct NotIntrospective {
    int a;
    double b;
    trackable c;
};

template<typename Visitor, typename T>
inline void visit_each(Visitor& visitor, const T& t, long) {
  visitor(t);    
} 

template<typename Visitor>
inline void visit_each(Visitor& visitor, const Introspective& t, int) {
  visitor(t); //"visits" the object as a whole

  //recursively visit the member objects; if unspecialized, will simply call `visitor(x)`
  visit_each(visitor, t.a, 0);
  visit_each(visitor, t.b, 0);
  visit_each(visitor, t.c, 0);
}

struct is_trackable {
  void operator()(const trackable&) { 
    //Do something
  }

  template<typename T>
  void operator()(const T&) { }
}

int main() {
    Introspective a;
    NotIntrospective b;
    trackable c;

    visit_each(is_trackable(), a, 0); //calls specialized version, finds `a.c`
    visit_each(is_trackable(), b, 0); //calls default version, finds nothing
    visit_each(is_trackable(), c, 0); //calls default version, which "visits" the 
                                      //object itself, and finds that it is trackable
}
```

The key thing is that `visit_each` itself doesn't do any magic, except provide a way for a call to `visit_each` to not fail to compile on an unrecognized type.

Comment: As far as I have seen, one normally derives from `signals::trackable`. Also, afaik, "subobject" refers to base-classes when used in the standard and as such I think it is used like that in Boost documentation too.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, that is the usual case.  But I am working under the assumption that they call `visit_each` on the provided slot, and if one of its members [specifically, one of the bound members of a `boost::bind` object] derives from `trackable` then it executes the code neccessary to track that particular object's lifetime and disconnect the slot appropriately.

Comment: Indeed, digging through the various bind headers, it looks like they specialize `visit_each` on `bind_t`, and the implementation calls `t.accept(v)`, and `bind_t::accept` in turn calls `visit_each(_f)` and `_1.accept(v)`.  That's as far as my boost-fu goes...I have no idea what type `_1` is, but I'm betting it ends up forwarding the `visit_each` to a bound argument.

Comment: `_l` seems to be the bound argument list.

Comment: @Xeo: "subobjects" means both base classes and members

Answer (score 2):

I guess this might be more helpful:

[Design Overview - `visit_each` function template](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals/s05.html)

Comment: That link doesn't really help me, as only the first sentence really tells something and the rest is about the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`visit_each` allows to inspect variables, bound by `boost::bind`. Canonical example is to inspect contents for `this` pointer and extract base `boost::signals::trackable` out of it.

```
class MyClass : boost::signals::trackable
{
    void my_method(int arg);
}

boost::signal<void()> signal;

signal.connect( boost::bind(&MyClass::my_method, this, 5) );
```

This way, the `boost::signal` will be able to accomplish safe callback subscription to the MyClass object.

Comment: Please note that Boost.Signals does not exist since Boost 1.69.  It's superseded by Boost.Signals2